# Android run different functions depend on country

Tags: java, android, country

I want to run different functions to my app depending of the country of the user
For example if Country is US then
do this
if country is UK then
do this

....could someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different approaches:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

gets the country according to the phone settings (this **can** be changed by the user), whereas

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

gets the country of the sim card (**can not** be changed by the user)

So you have the choice what fits your needs best

Comment: Though the second way won't work on devices witout a SIM/phone function, such as (some) tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29) to get the current user's Locale, and do whatever you like from the language code and country code that you get from that.